# How to search for a key and change the value of that?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

sample.txt:

```json
{"ip":"","port":0,"protocol":"udp","user":false,"test":false}
```

I want change the `'value'` to a particular `'key'` in the above dictionary.

For example: For `'port'`: I need to change `'23'`, for `'protocol'`, I need to change `'tcp'` etc. using Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data appears to be in JSON format, so you'd modify it by converting the JSON string to an object, change the properties, then convert the object back to a JSON string, like this:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\sample.txt'

(Get-Content $file -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
  $_.port     = 23
  $_.protocol = 'tcp'
  $_                   # echo current object to feed it back into the pipeline
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Set-Content $file
```

On PowerShell v2 or earlier you need to run `(Get-Content $file) | Out-String` to emulate the parameter `-Raw` that was introduced with v3.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with JSON, lets use JSON!

```
$json = Get-Content .\sample.txt | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.port = 23
$json.protocol = 'tcp'
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File .\sample.txt
```

- First I read the file and lets powershell convert it from JSON to an object. (Line 1)
- I can now edit this object. (Line 2-3)
- Finally I convert it back to JSON and write it to the file. (Line 4)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am little confused in this code. Can you please explain, how to change the 'port' to '30' and 'protocol'  to 'udp' using the code that you written. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The editing part of the portnumer is this part: 
$json **.port = 23**